# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^{k-1}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ for any $-1<a<b<1$.

Tags: real-analysis

I wish to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^{k-1}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ for any $-1<a<b<1$.

Clearly this series is the derivative of the geometric series , so my thought is to use the Weierstrass M test so that  $kx^{k-1} < kb^{k-1}$. Is is then true that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kb^{k-1}$ converges because it is the derivative of  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b^{k}$ which is convergent or perhaps I am on the wrong track. Hints appreciated.

Comment: Why not directly show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k b^{k-1}$ converges?

Comment: @shrinklemma how?

Comment: By comparing it to another geometric series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct implementation of the Weierstrass test here is

$$|kx^{k-1}|  = k|x|^{k-1} \leqslant kc^{k-1},$$

where $c = \max(|a|,|b|)$ and $0 < c < 1$.

I'll leave it to you to show that $\sum kc^{k-1}$ converges.

Hint: ratio test